# Filter number using preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In an php eCommerce implementation I got total cart price as $20.00 or $0.00 (in case empty cart). To filter the number from this string I'm using following

// $total may "$20.00" or "$0.00" or "$10,000.00" etc

```
$total = "$20.00";

return floatval( preg_replace( '/[^0-9,.]/', '',  $total) );
```

Its works when ther is value greater than 0 but fails in empty cart senario. Always returns a strange value 360!

Expected output are follows,

```
Input       Output

$20.00      20

$0.00       0

$10,000.00  10000
```

Comment: Dont store currency as a string. Have formatting in your template code, but store internally as integar

Comment: Remove `$` sign and `,` then cast to int or whatever.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue by the way. It's probably caused by code you haven't shared.

Comment: I'm trying inside wordpress wooCommerce plugin - WC()->cart->get_cart_total()   Ie, return  preg_replace( '/\..*|[^0-9]/', '',  WC()->cart->get_cart_total());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single preg_replace call

```
preg_replace( '/\..*|[^0-9]/', '',  $total)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yW7tL9/1)

Comment: If I were a shopper of this website I'd be very happy to know that I would get anything under  $1.00 for free.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is currency, I suggest you use the appropriate tool for it namely [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php):

Example:

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter("en_US",NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$fmt->parse("$10,123,234.23"); //Returns 10123234.23
$fmt->parse("$0.00"); //Returns 0
```

This also has the advantage of allowing to to internationalize in the future if you so choose. However this does require the [Internationalization Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension to be installed.